# angularjs component was rendered check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my component i need to manipulate SVG dom, do alter elements positions a bit, hence i need to know sizing of some children.

angular component lifecycle hooks doesn't fit my needs.

$onInit & $postLink both called when DOM is ready but has no sizing yet (wasn't rendered completely, and all elements sizes wasn't calculated width/height offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth all set to auto, and there is no possibility to get element size)

So it's only possible to do calculations with specific delay, using $timeout service.

Any better approach?

Comment: If anyone has concerns about the question please write them down before vote for closing

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout with 0ms delay. Code will be invoked when all components and directives will be rendered.

```
$timeout(function() {
   //your code here
});
```

Comment: I'm looking for better approach, as you can see i use $timeout already. BTW timeout 0ms doesn't fix this, rendering is slow, have too much watchers.